# Difference between vectors with same origin?

Tags: vectors

i have 4 vectors:

- $|\vec{AC}|=|\vec{AD}|$
- $|\vec{BC}|=|\vec{BE}|$

$\angle (\vec{AC}, \vec{AD}) $ =$\angle (\vec{BC}, \vec{BE}) $

[image: vector image]

if i know the len and angle of all vectors: how do I find the Distance between D and E ?

### EDIT expanding to more vectors

Given all possible vectors pairs that satisfy:

- $|\vec{xC}|=|\vec{xy}|$ Vector ends at C
- $\angle (\vec{xC}, \vec{xy}) $ =$\angle (\vec{BC}, \vec{BE}) $

how do you describe the line that forms between all points y. (line through y1, y2, and black dots in image)

[image: All y points]

Comment: are you trying to find the $distance$ between points D and E? Saying the "difference" is too vague. You could be referring to a change in y or a change in x or...

Comment: Distance. Im going to add some context in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $X$ as the position of $C$ and $\theta$ as the angle used

Isn't this defined by the parametric equations:
$$x(t) = t + (X-t) \cos\theta$$
$$y(t) = (X-t) \sin\theta$$
solving for $t$ gives:
$$ t=X-\frac{y}{\sin\theta}$$
Thus
$$x=X-\frac{y}{\sin \theta}+y\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
$$y=\frac{(X-x)\sin \theta}{1-\cos\theta}$$

The distance between two points is thus:
$$s=\sqrt{(y-y')^2+(x-x')^2}$$
$$s=\sqrt{(\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta})^2 (x-x')^2+(x-x')^2}$$
$$s=|x-x'|\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-\cos \theta}}$$
or if you want to put this back in terms of $t$:
$$s=|t-t'|\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}$$

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! 7

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec {DE} =\vec {DA}+\vec {AB}+\vec {BE} =-\vec {AD}+\vec {AB}+\vec {BE}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. How would you describe the line made of all the points formed with this construction by changing the length of the 2 vectors?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it a bit clearer, I want to describe the line that forms between all the possible points y