# Show that only 1 sphere that satisfies the following condition

Tags: vectors

(Following from: [Difference between vectors with same origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408458/difference-between-vectors-with-same-origin/3408686#3408686))

Given the parametric equations:

$x(t)=t+(X−t)cosθ$

$y(t)=(X−t)sinθ$

with $θ[0,2π)$ and $t>0$

where $X$ is a fixed point on the x axis.

The points with angle $θ$ can be seen as lying on a sphere centred at t with radius: $r=(X-t)$.

Below is a plot showing some of these points divided by angle, and the sphere they lie on.

[image: points and circles]

For a fixed $X$, and a point (x,y) that satisfies the condition:

$x(t, θ)=t+(X−t)cosθ$

$y(t, θ)=(X−t)sinθ$

## 1) Prove that there is only 1 solution $(t, θ)$

for 2 points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) with fixed $X,θ$ such that:

$x1(t, θ)=t+(X−t)cosθ$

$y1(t, θ)=(X−t)sinθ$

$x2(t+1, θ)=(t+1=+(X−(t+1))cosθ$

$y2(t+1, θ)=(X−(t+1))sinθ$

## 2) what is the angle $\Theta$ between (x1,y1) (x2,y2)?

Comment: What have you attempted? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: @PaulSinclair for point one conceptually it seems that every circle with smaller radius curves away from the bigger radius one and therefore no circle overlaps. Therefore expect for the single point where all the circles meet, no other point can be on 2 circles. But i have never written anything in a proof kind of way, so i need help writing this down in a formal way. 


for point 2 i calculated the slope between: x,y(t) and x,y(t+1): x= (delta(t) cos(angle))/(delta(t)+delta(t)cos(angle)) but i would like to see other solutions and confirm i did it correctly

Comment: That whole circle thing is a red herring. Just solve the equations for $t, \theta$. But as you've written it (1) is obviously false (if $(t,\theta)$ is a solution, so is $(t, \theta + 2\pi)$). Look back at the problem and see what restrictions have been placed on the values of $t$ and $\theta$. As for (2), The angle $\Theta$ between any two vectors is given by the formula $\vec u \cdot \vec v = \|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos \Theta$, where $\vec u \cdot \vec v$ is the inner product: $(x_1, y_1)\cdot (x_2, y_2) = x_1x_2 + y_1y_2$

Comment: @PaulSinclair the solution (t,θ+2π), is the same radius (t) and same angle, so it is the same solution. I need to show that if  (t,θ) is a solution, then there is no solution with a different t, and any angle. 

I probably wasn't clear in my explanation, I the slope of the x,y(t+n,θ) for n=real number >0. And the angle that this line forms with the x axis. 

I think I can use your formula with the result of the slope I calculated thouh

Comment: $\theta$ is a real number. If you want to use theta to represent an angle. This involves restricting $\theta$ to an inverval such as $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi, \pi]$. That would be a "restriction placed on the value of $\theta$" which you didn't give in the post. There are also restrictions on $t$. I didn't mention it, but there are solutions with $t < 0$ as well as $t > 0$, and they do overlap. Since you describe $t$ as a radius in your comment, you apparently want $t > 0$ But that again is a restriction you didn't bother to mention in your post. You need to give those restrictions IN YOUR POST.

Comment: You're right, I added the restrictions. Like this it matches the visual description. The equations are trying to describe the spherical construction. It comes from the Ewald sphere for diffraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that for each point $(x,y), x\ne X$, there is only one pair $t, \theta$ with $t > 0, 0 \le \theta <2\pi$ with $$x = t + (X - t) \cos \theta\\y = (X - t)\sin\theta$$ note that $$(x - t)^2 + y^2 = (X - t)^2\\t^2 - 2xt + x^2 + y^2 = t^2 - 2Xt + X^2\\x^2 + y^2-X^2 = 2(x - X)t\\t = \frac{x^2 + y^2-X^2}{2(x - X)}$$

(Excuse my comment above where I said there was also a solution with $t < 0$. I hadn't worked it all out in my head yet, and thought that the equation was quadratic in $t$.)
For $\theta$, note that $\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x - t}$. There is only one such $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ that gives the correct signs for both $x - t$ and $y$.

For (2), I assume what you mean is $$\begin{align}(x_1,y_1) &= (t + (X - t) \cos \theta, (X - t)\sin\theta)\\ (x_2,y_2) &= (t + 1 + (X - t - 1) \cos \theta, (X - t - 1)\sin\theta)\end{align}$$
(Pro-tip: If you want to see how someone else produced a bit of mathematics, right-click on it and select "Show Math As > TeX Commands". Also, consult the [MathJax Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).)

As I said in the comment, the quickest way to find the angle between any two real vectors (in any dimension) is by means of $$\vec v_1 \cdot \vec v_2 = \|v_1\|\|v_2\|\cos \Theta$$In this case, it will be helpful to let $q = (X - t)$
$$\begin{align}\vec v_1 \cdot \vec v_2 &= x_1x_2 + y_1y_2\\&= (t + q\cos \theta)(t + 1 + (q - 1)\cos \theta) + (q\sin \theta)((q - 1)\sin\theta)\\&= t(t+1) + (t(q - 1) + (t + 1)q)\cos\theta + q(q - 1)(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta)\\&= t(t+1) + (2qt + q - t)\cos\theta + q(q - 1)\end{align}$$
While $\|v_1\| = \sqrt{t^2 + q^2 + 2qt\cos\theta}, \|v_2\| = \sqrt{(t+1)^2 + (q-1)^2 + 2(q-1)(t+1)\cos\theta}$

So, $$\cos \Theta = \frac {t(t+1) + (2(X - t)t + X - 2t)\cos\theta + (X-t)(X - t - 1)}{\sqrt{\left(t^2 + (X - t)^2 + 2(X - t)t\cos\theta\right)\left((t+1)^2 + (X - t-1)^2 + 2(X - t -1)(t+1)\cos\theta\right)}}$$

Comment: brilliant, thanks !